# Simulate uniform external stroke using text-shadow with opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's slightly bizarre that in 2019 there is no standard and simple (and browser-independent) way to put a stroke effect around the *outside* of text using CSS.  We do have `-webkit-text-stroke` but it seems to be pretty browser dependent and also for some odd reason the stroke is centred around the border of the text rather than outside it, as [bemoaned here](https://css-tricks.com/text-stroke-stuck-middle/#article-header-id-0).

So I'm trying to implement a simulated stroke effect based on the ubiquitous `text-shadow` property, but to achieve a nice smooth stroke effect even for wide stroke (to avoid gaps between shadows) I'm using not just four shadows but many, as shown in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhrgna0f/), the code for which is:

```
var element = document.getElementById('random-text');
var strokeWidth = 2.3;
var strokeColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
var strokePart = '';
var increment = 0.1 * 1/strokeWidth;
increment = increment > 0.25 ? 0.25 : increment;
increment = increment * 2*Math.PI;
for (var angle = 0; angle < 2*Math.PI; angle += increment) {
    strokePart = strokePart + (angle > 0 ? ', ' : '') + (Math.cos(angle) * strokeWidth).toFixed(2) + 'px ' + (Math.sin(angle) * strokeWidth).toFixed(2) + 'px 0px ' + strokeColor;
}
style = 'text-shadow: ' + strokePart+ ';';
element.setAttribute('style', style);
```

This works nicely except that because it is made up of many overlapping shadows, the final opacity of the stroke is basically `1.0` or close to that.  But I want the opacity of the stroke to be a settable variable.

I could reduce the opacity of each sub-shadow (i.e. `strokeColor`) so that when they layer up the cumulative opacity is what I want, but my feeling is that it's better to let the opacity max out at `1.0` (set `strokeColor` to have `1.0` opacity) and then dial it down at the end to what you want.  Otherwise, you risk seeing gaps and/or variable opacity around the stroke.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

We could set the `opacity` of the text element, but that will change the opacity of the text too.  To overcome that, we could create a clone of the original text element, add the stroke to that (with new opacity), then place the original (unstroked) text on top, but if the text itself is partially transparent then you see the text under.  Maybe set the opacity of the text in the "stroked" layer to zero opacity first?  But this is all getting a bit complicated for what should be a very simple stroke effect!

Comment: This: https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Comment: @RandyCasburn I've read that article before but I can't see how it can be applied to solve the problem I mention.  A modification to my jsfiddle would be really handy, preferably one that modifies only the javascript part and not the separate css part, because of the context in which I need to apply this.

Comment: You said: _to put a stroke effect around the outside of text using CSS_ and then said my suggestion won't work in your comment because _to solve the problem I mention_ ? pardon my confusion, but what precisely is _the problem_?

Comment: The problem is how to alter the opacity of the shadow in my implementation above, where the shadow comprises multiple shadows blended combined together to form a simulated stroke: https://jsfiddle.net/jhrgna0f/

Comment: _in my implementation above_; got it. IMO you've over complicated something that is simple with four lines of CSS that us rgba() to set opacity. Good luck to you.